# How remove the last item on generate_series sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

I try create 10 min ranges for every day on 2016.

```
SELECT i::timestamp date_start, 
       i::timestamp + '599 second'::interval date_end,
       0::bit download
FROM generate_series('2016-01-01', 
                     '2017-01-01', 
                     '10 minute'::interval) i;
```

[image]

There are 366 days in 2016 so `366 days * 24 hours * 6 interval = 52704`

The last one row belong to 2017

I could just delete the last row, but want fix the query in case want to run it again in 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about subtracting 10 minutes from the end of the interval?

```
SELECT i::timestamp date_start, 
       i::timestamp + '599 second'::interval date_end,
       0::bit download
FROM generate_series('2016-01-01', 
                     '2017-01-01'::timestamp - interval '10 minute', 
                     '10 minute'::interval
                    ) i
```